# Highcharts timelines with a single data point

Tags: highcharts

when I am creating a timeline based highcharts chart, it fails to render time in x-axis when there is only a single point. An example: http://jsfiddle.net/EAmBG/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%e of %b'   
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9],
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
        }]
    });
});
```

Works perfectly when there's multiple point.

So far I haven't found a flag to fix this. Any tips on this one?

Thanks in advance, Timo

Comment: You probably just need to format the labels on your xAxis. But that looks fine to me. One point at midnight.

Answer (score 0):

You set the point start

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1)
```

this means `start at 2010/1/1 - 00:00:00` so as expected it start from this point.

If you set point start like this:

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1,5,3,7)
```

result is `2010/1/1 - 05:03:07`

Chart works logical. There is no problem. If you set one point then this should be start point. What is the problem about this?